# Clarification on React inheritance

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I have one inheritance case in React that one module `User` which has the components `UserList` and `UserForm` with its own functionalities such as display userelist in UserList component and submit a form in UserForm. In the root of the Project/Library it has also its own actions, reducers. Now I would like to use this component in multiple applications. What is the best option in React? What I have tried in regards of inheritance so far:

1. Created Core module include User (UserList, UserCreat/Edit) component.
2. Include this core module under Project1 >> Src
3. Extend it by overwriting Core-UserCreate/Edit Component

But I am not sure if it's a better solution or not. So could anyone please guide me on how can I achieve my functionality in the best way possible?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form, ButtonToolbar, Col, Row, Button, Alert  } from "react-bootstrap";
import _ from 'lodash';

import fields from "./fields.json";

class UserCreateEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fields: fields,
            label: "",
            name: "",
            type: "",
            placeholder: "",
            options: "",
            status:false,
            title:"Core:New User"
        };

        [
            "_handleSubmit",
            "_handleChange",
            "_handleFieldsSubmit",
            "_handleFieldsChange",
            "_handleCancel"
        ].map((fn) => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this));
    }
    static propTypes = {
        fields: PropTypes.array
    };
    _handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { label, name, type, placeholder, options } = this.state;

        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            fields: [
                ...prevState.fields, {
                    label,
                    name: name || `name--${prevState.fields.length}`,
                    type: type || "text",
                    placeholder,
                    options
                }
            ]
        }));
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // const { fields, title } = this.props;
        // if(!_.isUndefined(fields)){
        //  this.setState({
        //      fields:[...fields]
        //  });
        // }
        // if(!_.isUndefined(title)){
        //  this.setState({
        //      title:[...title]
        //  });
        // }
    }
    _handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    async _handleFieldsSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("json: ", JSON.stringify(this.state.fields));
        const obj = {};
        (Object.keys(this.refs) || []).forEach((i) => obj[this.refs[i].name] = this.refs[i].value || "");
        console.log('obj: ', obj);
        await this.props.saveUser({
            user: obj
        });
        console.log('"status" :', this.props.status);
        if(this.props.status){
            this.setState({
                status: this.state.status
            });
            this.props.history.push("/users");  
        }
    }
    _handleCancel = () => {
        this.props.history.push("/users");  
    } 
    _handleFieldsChange(e, i) { }
    render() {
        const fields = (this.state.fields || []).map((f, i) => {
            const { label, name, type, value: defaultValue, ...rest } = f;
            return (
                <Form.Group key={i} controlId={`form--${i}`}>
                    {(type !== "checkbox" && label) && <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>}
                    {(type === "checkbox") && (
                        <Form.Check
                            type={type}
                            name={`${name}`}
                            label={label}
                            defaultValue={defaultValue}
                            onChange={(e) => this._handleFieldsChange(e, i)}
                        />
                    )}

                    {(type !== "checkbox" && type !== "select") && (
                        <Form.Control
                            type={type}
                            name={`${name}`}
                            ref={`form__${name}__${i}`}
                            defaultValue={defaultValue}
                            onChange={(e) => this._handleFieldsChange(e, i)}
                            {...rest}
                        />
                    )}

                    {(type === "select") && (
                        <Form.Control
                            as="select"
                            name={`${name}`}
                            ref={`form__${name}__${i}`}
                            defaultValue={defaultValue}
                            onChange={(e) => this._handleFieldsChange(e, i)}
                        >
                            {(JSON.parse(f.options) || []).map((o) => <option key={o} value={o}>{o}</option>)}
                        </Form.Control>
                    )}
                </Form.Group>
            )
        });
        return (<div style={{ margin: 20 }}>
            <h4>{this.state.title}</h4>
            <Form className="mt-3 border-top py-3" onSubmit={this._handleFieldsSubmit} >
                {fields}
                {((this.state.fields || []).length > 0) && (
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                        <Button variant="primary" style={{ marginRight: 10 }} type='submit'>Save</Button>
                        <Button variant="danger" onClick={ () => this._handleCancel()}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                )}
            </Form>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default UserCreateEdit;
```

Inherit UserCreatEdit Form into Project1 to extends its functionality and UI

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {UserCreateEdit} from "../../../core";
import { saveUser } from "../../../core";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class UserForm extends UserCreateEdit {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fields: [
                ...this.state.fields,
                {
                    "label": "Phone",
                    "name": "phone",
                    "type": "text",
                    "placeholder": "Phone",
                    "options": ""
                }
            ],
            title:"Restaurant: New User"

        };
    }

    // render() {
    //  return (<div style={{ margin: 20 }}>
    //      <UserCreateEdit fields={this.state.fields} title={'Restaurant: New User'} />
    //  </div>);
    // }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    status: _.get(state, 'users.data.status', [])
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    saveUser: (payload) => dispatch(saveUser(payload))
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserForm));
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) from the react docs. Specifically, the [So What About Inheritance?](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) section. You should be able to customise `UserCreateEdit` to take props and change accordingly.

Comment: if you're talking about sharing code across different codebases, package your code and install it via npm.

Comment: @John Ruddell, Thanks for your replay. Sharing code across different codebase by the package is correct but What about if same code but different UI?

Comment: What do you mean by same code but different UI? if there's 2 UI's then theres code that runs each individually no?